# C# ActiveDirectory get PrincipalContext with "Rights"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, active-directory, principalcontext, usersession

I have a small web server running ASP.NET MVC on it. The Server is running with User "abc" but the User "abc" do not have rights for "changes" in ActiveDirectory.

So I have to pass the user login in the PrincipalContext with.

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, user, password))
{

    GroupPrincipal theGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupId);

    theGroup.Members.Add(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userId);

    theGroup.Save();

}
```

the Code does work. But I do not like to transfair a Password from Methode to Methode...
=> on MVC I have a SSO and the Server knows me

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

It is possible to Use this Information?

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, [System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User]) ???
```

Or MUST I give the password. And how to best pass from view to this method.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is called "impersonation". As long as you are using Windows authentication, you can do it with the [`WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate) method:

```
using (var ctx = ((WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate()) {
    // Anything done here will use the user's credentials
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution does not Work with PrincipalContext!? I think I'm doing something wrong. if I hand over the password directly, its possible to add users... the callback with WindowsIdentity is: "Access is denied"

Comment: You are creating the `PrincipalContext` inside the `using`?

Comment: And you removed the `user, password` from the `PrincipalContext` constructor?